# Cockpit reload login page after login

Tags: login, cockpit

I am using ubuntu 20.04.1 and installed the cockpit from the official backport.
Cockpit login page loads (even if I put in wrong credentials it shows  [Wrong user name or password]) but when I put the correct username and password, the login page reload itself.

below is the syslog

```
cockpit-ws[3405]: cockpit-ws: Failed to open certificate file /run/cockpit/tls/e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996bb92427ae41e4749b934ca495991b7852b855: No such file or directory
cockpit-session[3423]: **pam_ssh_add: Failed adding some keys**
cockpit-session[3423]: pam_unix(cockpit:session): session opened for user john by (uid=0)
systemd-logind[911]: New session 5 of user john.
systemd[1]: Started Session 5 of user john.
polkitd(authority=local)[900]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:5 (system bus name :1.38 [cockpit-bridge], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
cockpit-ws[3405]: User john logged into session 5
cockpit-ws[3405]: cockpit-ws: Failed to open certificate file /run/cockpit/tls/e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996bb92427ae41e4749b934ca495991b7852b855: No such file or directory
```

And web browser console shows,

```
(index):265 GET http://as400i.com:9090/cockpit/login **401 (Authentication failed)**
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same issue (even with an invalid psw also), using Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.

At first, I thought it might be because I was using `http` (not yet `https`). Therefor I created the file `/etc/cockpit/cockpit.conf` with content like so:

```
[WebService]
AllowUnencrypted = true
```

But that didn't solve my problem (yet). I also had to perform these commands:

```
sudo systemctl start cockpit.socket
sudo systemctl enable cockpit.socket
```

After I issued these commands, I was able to login.